# Configuring my cable modem/gateway to hide its country location

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, cable-modem

My ISP is a cable company which provides the modem/gateway but has fully configurable access.  I want to be able to use websites in the U.S. that don't allow me to access them outside of the country (e.g. Hulu, HBO-Go, Amazon VOD, etc).  In fact I subscribe (and pay monthly fee) to several of these, which I use when I'm at my U.S. address.
I tried simple DNS services, for $5 per month, and that works only for a couple of them like Netflix.
Is my solution a VPN service of some kind?  do they help in setting up my modem with the necessary tweaks that will "fool" these content providers into thinking I am physically in the U.S.? 
I've asked these questions and the VPN providers say "sure ... just sign up & pay for our service and we'll help you get your programs."    but I tried this with one and their tech support was so poor that I never did get my equipment set up properly.  Had to reformat my computer, in fact.

I'm just trying to get the programming here in Mexico that I pay for in the U.S. ... nothing more.
The DNS service told me I could try setting up my (spare) router, feeding it off of my cable modem;  but they never did tell me how to do it.
Please help with suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe these websites resolve your location based on your IP address, so I think the only way for you to make the websites believe you are in another country is to have an IP address that would geolocate within that country - so a VPN or proxy might be your only solution. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I used a service for a while that supported the Windows VPN client, and successfully used Hulu and Netflix on that PC. They also had decent support for installing client software on other operating systems. I'd avoid fiddling with the router that provides your internet connection. It's all too easy to lose your connection altogether. If you have a spare, look at using that. Not all routers support operating as a VPN client, though. Look at installing [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) if it supports your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

The factor that is stopping you from accessing US websites to their full potential is that your IP address is not a recognized IP address originating from that region. This is largely in part to legal restraints on the websites that host and offer those programmes - they may not be licensed for viewing in Mexico, but they are in the US. You cannot configure your cable modem to have a US IP address as your internet service provider will only have Mexican IP addresses available and so no matter how much you try, the cable modem will *always* have a Mexican IP and because of that, content available from those websites is not accessible.

It's a two-way conversation; the websites asks where your modem is and the modem says "I'm from Mexico!". It's at that point the website says "Sorry bub, I can't deal with you.." and stops you from getting your content. The modem cannot lie, either, so it's a pretty definitive situation.

There are workarounds, however.

Although your cable modem will always have a Mexican IP and canoot lie, there is nothing to say your desktop/laptop/tablet computer has to have one. This is where VPNs come in ([for more information on VPNs and how they work..](http://www.howstuffworks.com/vpn.htm)). VPNs can be utilized for loads of cool stuff but for your scenario you only need to be concerned with [using a VPN to tunnel your internet traffic](http://www.whyvpn.com/vpn-watch-tv-shows/).

So - say you connect to the internet in Mexico through a laptop computer with a cable modem. You connect up and you have a Mexican IP, and because you have that IP, you cannot access Hulu, HBO-Go etc (again, the modem cannot lie). You can instead use a VPN to tunnel your internet traffic through a server in the US and cut out that question ever being asked to the modem. Instead, that question of "Where are you?" is asked to and answered by "I'm in the States!" - from the VPN server.

Imagine piping all your internet traffic through that server and out the other end - think of it (quite literally!) as a tunnel, across the border and out the other side. To all websites, your laptop computer will appear to be based in the US because it looks like it's physically located there (even though the VPN server you are routing through is, and your laptop is actually in Mexico) and therefore, regional restrictions will be lifted. [There is a good explanation of VPNs and how they work on YouTube here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=g6zFRcKavqI#t=159)

You aren't modifying the modem in any way, instead you're just routing everything your computer does through a server in the US before it getting passed back to you. So to all intents and purposes, you can utilize a US-side internet connection.

Unfortunately, VPN providers to charge for this service. [There are free ones](https://www.tunnelbear.com/) and [there are paid ones](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/), the main caveat being the free ones only allow you to tunnel so much data before becoming a paid service (500mb or so). Paid services worth it in my opinion - I use a VPN for a very different reason (related to privacy and security) and I cannot imagine a life without one now!

[There are resources out there](http://vpnfreedom.com/hulu/how-to-watch-hulu-outside-the-us/) for further reading but yes, a VPN service would be your best bet in my opinion.

Comment: comprehensive, clear explanation: thanks, runtime05!

Comment: if he answered your question well, you might want to select his answer as best!

Comment: You're more than welcome! :)